# How find this $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{500}=b_{1}+b_{2}+\cdots+b_{500}$?

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A=\{1^2,2^2,3^2,\cdots,1000^2\}$. How to prove :

There exist $A_{1}=\{a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},\cdots,a_{500}\}\subset A$, $A_{2}=\{b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{500}\}\subset A$, such that $A_{1}\bigcup A_{2}=A,A_{1}\bigcap A_{2}=\varnothing$, and  $a_{1}+a_{2}+\cdots+a_{500}=b_{1}+b_{2}+\cdots+b_{500}$ ?

Comment: What is  question ? **Prove** or **T/F**?

Comment: Why *always* ? Your $A$ is fixed. Should it be $A=\{1^2,2^2,\cdots,n^2\}$ ?

Comment: @arbautjc ,No,I mean there alway exists $A_{1},A_{2}$, we must look for this $A_{1},A_{2}$.

Comment: Then, why say *always*? It means, implicitly, that there is some variable in the statement, but there is none. If you find a solution, it will always be there, needless to say!

Comment: Why has this one close vote as "not a real question"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**N.B.** This does not solve your question because it gives you two subsets of (possibly) smaller size than the half which are disjoint but have the same sum. Look at this proof and see if you can salvage something from this method - it could give an idea:
Let $n=500$ and let $B\subseteq A$ such that $|B|=n$. Then 
$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=1^2+...+n^2\leq\sum_{b\in B} b\leq(n+1)^2+...+(2n)^2=\frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{6}-\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
Hence there are 
$$\frac{2n(2n+1)(4n+1)}{6}-2\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+1=2n^3+n^2+1$$
options for the sum of the elemnents of $B$ (probably less, but that wont matter).
The number of subsetes of $A$ with $n$ elements is $\binom{2n}{n}$.
Since for all $n>5$ we have $\binom{2n}{n}>2n^3+n^2+1$, by the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), there exist $B_1\neq B_2\subseteq A$ with $|B_1|=|B_2|=n$ such that $\sum_{b\in B_1}b=\sum_{b\in B_2}b$. Now, denote $C=B_1\cap B_2$ and then $A_i=B_i\setminus C$. Clearly $\sum_{a\in A_1}a=\sum_{a\in A_2}a$ and $A_1\cap A_2=\emptyset$ and $|A_1|=|A_2|$. The problem is that it could be $|A_1|\neq n$.

Answer (score 12):

Note that 
$$(k+1)^2+(k+2)^2 = k^2+(k+3)^2\quad -4.$$
Therefore,
$$\tag1(k+1)^2+(k+2)^2+(k+4)^2+(k+7)^2 = k^2+(k+3)^2+(k+5)^2+(k+6)^2.$$
Now partition $A$ into $125$ groups of $8$ consecutive numbers each and distribute each such group among $A_1$ and $A_2$ accoring to $(1)$. This works because $1000$ is a multiple of $8$.

Comment: oh,very beatifull solution! @Hagen von Eitzen my frend.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: +1 for a very nice solution!