# A Combinatorial Problem

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

From any set of 5 distinct one-digit positive integers can we always choose two disjoint non-empty subsets , so that their elements have the same sum ?

Comment: Look at my answer at the link. Can you write a similar argument here? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359327/how-find-this-a-1a-2-cdotsa-500-b-1b-2-cdotsb-500/359357#359357

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**:
How many different subsets of a five element set are there?
How many possible sums of elements are there?
What happens if you found two non-disjoint sets?

Comment: Well,possible non-empty subsets = 31 , but the best estimate I get of the possible sum values is 9+8+7+6+5=35, so I can not apply box-principle, it would be easy if the question was concerning 6 numbers ; and I am not even sure whether the answer will be in positive!

Comment: You can get a better estimate: the smallest possible sum is the least element $j$, while the largest possible is $30+j$...

Comment: Um, still then from $j$ to $30+j$ , these are $31$ variations,not strictly greater than $31$

Comment: Now note that the sum can be $30+j$ only if $9,8,7,6$ are all in your starting set. In this case you have $9+6=8+7$. Otherwise the maximal sum is $\leq 29+j$, which completes your argument.

Comment: Ah! yes, that's quite correct , thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes 
Restating the problem: 
Let A=1,2,3,...,9 
Let B⊂A:n(B)=5 
Let C,D⊂B:(n(C)≠0)∧(n(D)≠0)∧(n(C∩D)=0) 
Show ∀B ∃C,D:(∑x∈C)=(∑y∈D)

Demonstrate by contrapositive: Suppose ∃B: ∀C,D (∑x∈C)≠(∑y∈D) 
Since there are only 126 unique sets B, it isn't difficult to show that there is no B which satisfies the contrapositive supposition, therefore it will have been shown that 
∀B ∃C,D:(∑x∈C)=(∑y∈D) is a valid conclusion.

Sorry I didn't have time for a more elegant solution.

Also if you continue with a possible sum values approach remember that C,D are restricted to be disjoint and non-empty, so the max possible sum for any given C,D is 6+7+8+9=30, not 35.

Comment: Your answer is poorly formatted to an extent that it severely hampers the reader. Please consider using $\LaTeX$ formatting; information can be found e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).